# JPA Not persisting an object J2EE

Tags: java, jpa

I have a legacy app using JEE5 , I add a class "People" and add "by hand" in the database a lot of records (people only has peopleid and a string peopledesc)

If I use the method getAllPeople() I get the list correctly populated, every data is there

But when I try to persist a new record by code using  persistPeople(People pep) It just does nothing

The system.out.println shows the description added to the object so the new created object is passed to the method, but it is not persisted in the database :(

No error is shown in the console output.

People.java

```
@Entity
public class People implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idpeople;

    private String desc;
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="PersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>entities.People</class>
```

......

```
PeopleDAOImPL.JAVA 

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
import residencias.dominio.Renovacion;


@Stateless
public class PeopleDAOImpl implements PeopleDAO {


   //EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersistenceUnit");


    @PersistenceUnit(unitName="PersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;


    @Override
    public void persistPeople(People pep) {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        System.out.println("description is  :"+pep.getDesc());
        em.persist(pep);


    }


    @Override
    public List<People> getAllPeople() {



        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        List<People> results = new ArrayList();
        Query queryPrincipal;

        try {


            queryPrincipal = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM People p");




            results = queryPrincipal.getResultList();

            return results;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(results.size());
            return results;

        } finally {
            if (em != null) {
                emf.close();
                em.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While during the invocation of a query, you are not obliged to be running within a transaction, when you try to persist / update state of an entity you must be running that particular action within a transaction boundary.

In your case you could use following configuration:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class PeopleDAOImpl implements PeopleDAO {

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName="PersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void persistPeople(People pep) {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        System.out.println("description is  :"+pep.getDesc());
        em.persist(pep);


    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried your solution but I got a null pointer exception when calling EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();